# The LINQ expression could not not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to maintain child-grandchildren relationship. I need to distinguish which children returned which grandchildren.

Query returns

```
"InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 
'x =>x.Children.AsQueryable().Select(c => new 
 {
 ItemNo= c.ItemNo,
 GrandChildItemNos = c.Children.AsQueryable().Select(gc => gc.ItemNo).ToList()
 })
.ToDictionary(keySelector: c => c.ItemNo, elementSelector: c => c.GrandChildItemNos)' could 
 not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to 
 client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 
'AsAsyncEnumerable','ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See 
 https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."
```

I think EF has problem translating .ToDictionary() part to SQL. Can anyone help on this.

Comment: The Title is ambiguous, given that EF generally _does_ retain relationships well on its own. This issue is specifically about projecting an EF query into a Dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close!

When you move the `ToDictionary()` beyond the point of materializing (the `ToListAsync()`) it will work. This is in fact what the error message also says: "or switch to client evaluation explicitly". The `ToDictionary` call cannot be translated into a query.

```cs
var childDetails = await context.Items.Where(w => w.ItemNo == parentItemNo)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Children
        .Select(c => new
        {
            c.ItemNo,
            GrandChildItemNos = c.Children.Select(gc => gc.ItemNo)
        })
    )
    .ToListAsync();
var dictionary = childDetails.ToDictionary(d => d.ItemNo, d => d.GrandChildItemNos);
```

This is my result:

[image]

Comment: Can I have this returned as an array of dictionaries, like the data structure I have shown above. Rite now it returns a dictionary with many elements like this -> { "A": ["AQ11"], "B": [ ], "C": ["CN22", "CL33"] }.

Comment: I don't understand what structure you want. The Dictionary contains KeyValuePairs where the Key is "A" or "B" and their respective Values are ["AQ11"] and [].

Comment: I have got it resolved. thank you.